# Scraping Websites via Google Cached Pages pages has been blocked

Tags: proxy-server

I'm trying to create a Service that Scraping websites by using Google Cached Pages.

**Example**

```
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:nike.com
```

The Response that I get is the HTML from Google cache, which is an older version of the Nike site.

And it works fine as long as I run it locally on my computer,
but when I deploy to google cloud platform, there I use porxy server
I get a 403 error that I can not access the information through a porxy server

**Example of response from proxy server**

> 433. That’s an error.
>
> Your client does not have permission to get URL `/s
> earch?q=cache:http://nike.com` from this server.  (Client IP address: XX.XXX.XX.XXX)<br
>
> Please see Google's Terms of Service posted at
> https://policies.google.com/terms
>
> If you believe that you
> have received this response in error, please report your
> problem. However, please make sure to take a look at our Terms of
> Service (http://www.google.com/terms_of_service.html). In your email,
> please send us the **entire** code displayed below.  Please also
> send us any information you may know about how you are performing your
> Google searches-- for example, "I' m using the Opera browser on Linux
> to do searches from home.  My Internet access is through a dial-up
> account I have with the FooCorp ISP." or "I'm using the Konqueror
> browser on Linux t o search from my job at myFoo.com.  My machine's IP
> address is 10.20.30.40, but all of myFoo' s web traffic goes through
> some kind of proxy server whose IP address is 10.11.12.13."  (If y ou
> don't know any information like this, that's OK.  But this kind of
> information can help us track down problems, so please tell us what
> you can.)
>
> We will use all this information to diagnose the
> problem, and we'll hopefully have you back up and searching with
> Google agai n quickly!
>
> Please note that although we read all
> the email we receive, we are not always able to send a personal
> response to each and every email.  So don't despair if you don't hear
> back from u s!
>
> Also note that if you do not send us the
> **entire** code below, *we will not be able to help
> you*.
>
> Best wishes,
> The Google

Article that talks about the problem https://proxyserver.com/web-scraping-crawling/scraping-websites-via-google-cached-pages/

How can I solve this problem, and run requests from the cloud as well without being blocked? Add parameters?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you should add a property in the header of your http request 
for example :

```
URL u = new URL("https://www.google.com//search?q=c");
        URLConnection c = u.openConnection();
        c.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "MSIE 7.0");
```

or

```
HttpRequest request =HttpRequest.newBuilder(new URI("https://www.google.com//search?q=c")).header("User-Agent", "MSIE 7.0").GET().build();
// note to change the URI
```

this two examples are in Java but the same concept is applied in all environments I guess 
hope that was helpfull